# Adding GStreamer to Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gstreamer, yocto

I've been trying to add gstreamer in Eclipse  for cross-platform compilation of an Variscite I.mx6 development kit. GStreamer-SDK is installed according to Installing on Linux - GStreamer SDK documentation - GStreamer SDK documentation for the Ubuntu Host I'm running eclipse on. Now the problem is; according to the Ubuntu installation guide, I need to include into the gcc command the following string:

`pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`

Most solutions i found on the web add this string to the eclipse project settings under C/C++ Build->Settings and configure there the gcc command line. Since I'm using the yocto project with the Yocto Project-plugin in Eclipse, I don't have access to those tabs anymore as I use a toolchain to cross compile my application. I've found other solutions from modifying the make file (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1164725) or adding the command line to the Autotools configure settings. I've tried both, but they didn't work. I've also added the gstreamer SDK under Includes with the following path: /opt/gstreamer-sdk/.

If anyone could help me out with this problem on how to configure Eclipse or my makefile, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

follow this instruction to **compile gstreamer sdk** using **eclipse IDE**
Note:
  compile using hello world gstreamer application program

1. goto properties in your **project->c/c++build->tool settings->settings**
    
   under **gcc compiler select the include section** and add the following details
    
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/gstreamer-0.10`
   `/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/glib-2.0`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/lib/glib-2.0/include`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/glib-2.0/glib`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/glib-2.0/gobject`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/libxml2/`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/ogg`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/theora`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/vorbis`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/wavpack`
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/gtk-2.0/gtk`
2. now goto **Build Steps** section
   and add this command into **pre-build steps**
   `/opt/gstreamer-sdk/bin/gst-sdk-shell`
3. goto **c/c++ Build->Environment** and add the following data into it
   Note:
   these information are noting but script data from **"/opt/gstreamer-sdk/bin/gst-sdk-shell"**
   `GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT  /opt/gstreamer-sdk`
   `GST_REGISTRY_1_0 ${HOME}/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/gstreamer-sdk-registry`
   `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/etc/xdg${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS:+:$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS}:/etc/xdg`
   `LDFLAGS   ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/lib ${LDFLAGS}`
   `XDG_DATA_DIRS /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/share${XDG_DATA_DIRS:+:$XDG_DATA_DIRS}:/usr/local/share:/usr/share`
   `PYTHONPATH  ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/lib/python2.7/site-packages${PYTHONPATH:+:$PYTHONPATH}`
   `GIO_EXTRA_MODULES  ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/lib/gio/modules`
   `CXXFLAGS   ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/include ${CXXFLAGS}`
   `GST_PLUGIN_SCANNER  ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/libexec/gstreamer-0.10/gst-plugin-scanner`
   `GST_PLUGIN_SCANNER_1_0  ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/libexec/gstreamer-1.0/gst-plugin-scanner`
   `CFLAGS   ${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/include ${CFLAGS}`
   `PKG_CONFIG_PATH /opt/gstreamer-sdk/lib/pkgconfig:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/lib/pkgconfig:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/share/pkgconfig${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH}`
   `PATH  /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/bin${PATH:+:$PATH}:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`
   `GST_REGISTRY  ${HOME}/.gstreamer-0.10/gstreamer-sdk-registry`
   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:${GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT}/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

   save the project and build it .. it should compile without error
4. now add the argument files into the run configuration
   right click the project and select **RunAs->RunConfiguration->create new(if not created)config file->argument(x)**
   add the input files and output files here 
   `ex:`
   `test.ogg output-test.ogg`
5. now run the project if everything is fine.
6. **Note:**
   this above procedure is for **x86 architecture only** if you are using other than x86 arch ,then include  appropriate architecture libraries and files to compile and exclude which are not needed!!!!!